Laravel 11 migration: preserving original attributes when updating existing column
Starting from Laravel 11, migrations are required to include all attributes of a column in such cases, even those that are not being modified. Otherwise, those attributes will be lost. However, this poses a challenge for me, as I don't want to constantly look up all the attributes of the column and define them explicitly.

Modifying Columns - Laravel 11 Upgrade Guide


For example, imagine you have a migration that creates a votes column
with the unsigned, default, and comment attributes:
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('votes')->unsigned()->default(1)->comment('The vote count');
});

Later, you write a migration that changes the column to be nullable as
well:
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('votes')->nullable()->change();
});

In Laravel 10, this migration would retain the unsigned, default, and
comment attributes on the column. However, in Laravel 11, the
migration must now also include all of the attributes that were
previously defined on the column. Otherwise, they will be dropped:
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('votes')
        ->unsigned()
        ->default(1)
        ->comment('The vote count')
        ->nullable()
        ->change();
});


How can I preserve the original column-settings when updating the attributes of an existing column in a migration from Laravel 11?
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('votes')->nullable()->change();
});

The expected result is that, alongside setting the column to nullable, it automatically retains the unsigned, default(1), and comment values as well. And I don't even want to look up the column type for such a minor change-whether it's a string, integer, etc., its exact length, and so on.

They already state in L11 that "In Laravel 10, this migration would retain the unsigned, default, and comment attributes on the column. However, in Laravel 11, the migration must now also include all of the attributes that were previously defined on the column. Otherwise, they will be dropped:"

the only way to preserve the original column-settings is to extend and change their migrations class.

Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Actually, I've already solved my issue, but it's quite complicated to provide a full working reproduction here as a response. It's not overly complex; the main logic on my part was simply to avoid having to manually assemble the previous attributes. Instead, I wanted it to automatically retain them based on the database content, similar to how it's done with Doctrine DBAL. In short, my solution was a Blueprint::macro('column', fn (string $name) => ...);; with a Schema::macro('getColumnsFully', fn () => ...); what a extended getColumns.

By the way, I can somewhat relate to the idea of "simplification". My only issue is with a custom internal package that handles multiple DB structures for a single Laravel project through migrations. For me, repeating things isn’t very necessary; migrations are really only needed during development to run them, and once they're finalized, I just need to apply them across all production environments, once.

TL;DR
This will be a somewhat lengthy answer, as multiple steps are required to implement this. In short, the idea is to create a macro for the Blueprint class named column.
Using this macro, we can instantly fetch all the current properties from the database and associate them with the column so that you don't have to manually specify them again.

Note: Of course, the code could be written much more elegantly, but to simplify the answer, I focused only on the macro logic. How this is implemented in one's own project is a matter of perspective. For now, I'm working on a package that will provide this for Laravel 11+.

Create column macro for Blueprint
Blueprint::macro('column', function (string $column) {
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $this */

    $table = $this->getTable();

    // Based on the column name and $this->getTable(), all data about the column can be retrieved from the database, including its type, indexes, etc.

    $definition = $this->addColumn($type, $column, $parameters);

    // $definition->nullable(true/false);
    // $definition->autoIncrement(true/false);
    // etc. here

    return $definition->change();
});

To create the definition, we need to know the column type and other parameters that will be used to define the column in Laravel, e.g., string; length: 100.
The column macro should return a valid definition, which we can then customize. I suggest returning it with a ->change() call right away, as the column macro is only used for modifying columns, so there's no point in postponing it.
Between the creation of the $definition and the return, we need to set the settings queried from the SQL for the $definition, such as unique, primary key, unsigned, etc. Otherwise, due to changes made in Laravel 11, these settings would be "deleted", meaning they wouldn't be applied, even if they were already set for the column. This explanation is the longest, so I have written it separately:
Querying column data using $this and Schema
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $this */

$table = $this->getTable();

// The schema returns the data for all columns of the table (unfortunately)
$columns = Schema::getColumns($table); // This actually gives quite a limited result, as it doesn't reveal whether the column is unique or a primary key from a single boolean variable, and this is what makes the response more complex.
// Finding the column with the current name
$columnData = collect($columns)->firstWhere('name', $column);

// And it's necessary to have the column's "Laravel" type, for example, for a varchar column, this would mean string in the Blueprint... I have only shared the logic
// $columnData['type_name'] example: varchar what will string
$type_laravel_name = match ($columnData['type_name']) {
   'varchar', 'char' => 'string',
   'text', 'smalltext', 'mediumtext', 'longtext' => 'text',
   'tinyint' => 'tinyInteger',
   ...
};

// And based on the type, the details also need to be determined (for example, the length for a varchar), I have only shared the logic
// $columnData['type'] example: varchar(100) where details: ['length' => 100]
$type_details = match ($type_laravel_name) => {
    'string' => [
        'length' => (int) Str::of($columnData['type'])->match('/\((\d+)\)/')->toString() ?: null,
        'compressed' => Str::of($columnData['type'])->lower()->contains('compressed'),
    ],
    'float' => [
        'precision' => (int) Str::of($columnData['type'])->match('/\((\d+)\)/')->toString(),
    ],
    // ...
};

// The $type_laravel_name and $type_details are necessary for creating the $definition, so we don't have to manually specify again that we're dealing with a varchar that is 100 characters long
$definition = $this->addColumn($type_laravel_name, $column, $type_details);

Setting the current configs that can be queried
// Is nullable?
$definition->nullable($columnData['nullable']);

// Has default value?
if (! is_null($columnData['default'])) {
    // Handle special cases becuase $columnData['default'] will be a string in every case
    $defaultValue = match ($type_laravel_name) {
        'int', 'smallInteger', '...' => (int) $default,
        'float', 'double', 'decimal' => (float) $default,
        'boolean', 'bool' => filter_var($default, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'json' => json_decode($default, true) ?? '{}',
        'binary', 'varbinary', 'blob' => base64_decode($default),
        default => $default, // Leave unknown types unchanged
    };
    $definition->default($default);
}

$definition->autoIncrement($columnData['auto_increment']);

// Is unsigned?
$definition->unsigned(Str::of($columnData['type'])->lower()->contains('unsigned'));

// Has comment?
if (! is_null($columnData['comment'])) {
    $definition->comment($columnData['comment']);
}

// And once everything is set, we can return. These settings can be overridden again outside of the migration, if necessary
return $definition->change();

Usage in Migration
In a migration, when modifying a column using the column macro, there is no need to call the change function or set other parameters. We have the ability to modify the set parameters, such as the type, or for example, the length for a varchar, whether it is nullable, and so on.
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->column('column')->type('string')->length(100)->autoIncrement(false);

    $table->column('another_1_column')->nullable();
    $table->column('another_2_column')->nullable(false);

    // ...
});

Eliminating IDE warnings for certain properties

Note: If the IDE warning doesn't bother you, you can skip it; it doesn't affect the macro's functionality, it just helps the IDE.


Customizing ColumnDefinition to prevent the IDE from showing warnings when using otherwise existing methods.
In the first instance, I needed to externally extend the PHPDoc content of the ColumnDefinition. The ColumnDefinition is built on Fluent, allowing variables to be managed within it. Values like unsigned or autoIncrement that can be assigned to a column also fall into this category. By default, Laravel conceals the fact that these variables can accept boolean values, which is understandable since the new Schema mechanism requires specifying all necessary properties for every migration; otherwise, they are lost.
However, my modification assigns the current properties to the column when it is being modified. This necessitates that all parameters, including true/false and other customizability options, are available beyond their default values for property removal. I raised a separate question regarding the PHPDoc extension needed for this purpose, which can be read at Expanding the PHPDoc of a PHP class what found in a Composer package.
For this solution, the column macro definition needs to be added to the Blueprint, and the extended autoIncrement and unsigned specifications need to be added to the ColumnDefinition, which look like this:
// ide-helper.php

/**
 * @method \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition column(string $column) Set column properties for change
 */
class Blueprint
{
    //
}

if (! class_exists(Blueprint::class)) {
    class_alias(Blueprint::class, \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::class);
}


/**
 * @method $this autoIncrement(bool $value = true) Set INTEGER columns as auto-increment (primary key) or NON-auto-increment
 * @method $this unsigned(bool $value = true) Set the INTEGER column as UNSIGNED (MySQL) or NON-UNSIGNED
 */
class ColumnDefinition
{
    //
}

if (! class_exists(ColumnDefinition::class)) {
    class_alias(ColumnDefinition::class, \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition::class);
}

Sources

Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint - Laravel 11 API Docs
Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition - Laravel 11 API Docs
Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable - Laravel 11 API Docs
Expanding the PHPDoc of a PHP class - StackOverflow answer

Reflection on the Laravel Docs example

In Laravel 10, this migration would retain the unsigned, default, and
comment attributes on the column. However, in Laravel 11, the
migration must now also include all of the attributes that were
previously defined on the column. Otherwise, they will be dropped:
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('votes')
        ->unsigned()
        ->default(1)
        ->comment('The vote count')
        ->nullable()
        ->change();
});


However, with my column macro, if I only want to modify the nullable on an existing column and keep all other attributes intact, the modification would look like this:
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->column('votes')->nullable();
});

